# How to create 2 environments in tox with different library version

Tags: python, tox

I need to test my library on the same python version but different dependent package version using `tox`. I have tried this:

```
[tox]
requires =
    tox>=4
env_list = py{37,38,39,310,311,typeguard_{v2,v3}}

[testenv]
description = run unit tests
deps =
    -rrequirements.txt
commands =
    pytest {posargs:tests}

[testenv:typeguard_{v2,v3}]
description = run tests with typeguard versions
base_python =
    py310: python3.10
deps =
    v2: typeguard<3.0.0
    v3: typeguard>=3.0.0
    -rrequirements.txt
commands =
    pytest {posargs:tests}
```

But it looks like it uses the latest `typeguard` version in all tests. The `requirements.txt` holds `typeguard` without a specific version.

How can this be configured to create two environments with different `typeguard` versions?

Comment: Have you tried placing the `-rrequirements.txt` below the other ones?

Comment: Same issue :(. I eddited the code so the `requirements.txt` will be last.

Comment: It seems like maybe the issue (or at least part of it) is in `env_list`. You should run `tox -l` to see the list of environments and check that it matches what you expect. Maybe what you want is `env_list =  py{37,38,39,310,311},typeguard_{v2,v3}`.

Comment: Seems like you might also want to replace the underscore `_` by a dash `-`: `env_list =  py{37,38,39,310,311},typeguard-{v2,v3}`. This is so that you can still use `v2: typeguard<3` in `deps`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @sinoroc pointed out, the problem is with `env_list`. To `py{}` and `typeguard-{}` should be separated. So should be the addressing to those environments based on the full environment name i.e. `v2` and `v3`.

```
[tox]
requires =
    tox>=4
env_list = py{37,38,39,310,311},typeguard-{v2,v3}

[testenv]
description = run unit tests
deps =
    -rrequirements.txt
commands =
    pytest {posargs:tests}

[testenv:typeguard-{v2,v3}]
description = run tests with typeguard versions
base_python = py310
deps =
    v2: typeguard<3.0.0
    v3: typeguard>=3.0.0
    -rrequirements.txt
commands =
    pytest {posargs:tests}
```

This is the corrected code

Comment: I am not quite sure that the `py310:` in `base_python = py310: python3.10` make sense.